# Saml 2.0: Why is NotBefore in the schema for SubjectConfirmationData if it is not allowed?

Tags: saml-2.0

We have several service providers using Saml 2.0 for single sign-on and they are all working fine.  Our most recent addition is balking because we send a NotBefore attribute on the SubjectConfirmationData element.  As far as I can tell, this is part of the xsd schema for Saml 2.0 (https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd) but then it is marked as MUST NOT in this profiles PDF (https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, the Web Browser SSO profile - which is the one you are using to provide single sign on for your users as an Identity Provider - dictates that you should not set NotBefore. The profile sets further limitations to the schema defined for Assertion to be used generically, which is totally fine.

The service provider at hand strictly checks compliance and thus rejects your Assertion. The fact that it has been working so far probably means that the other service provider implementations were more lenient.

Comment: My question is, why the conflict?  Why have it in the schema at all if you aren't supposed to use it?

Comment: There is no conflict. The schema defines how the assertion can be structured and different profiles set their own limitations. As you can see in https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf, it's only the Web Browser SSO profile that sets this limitation, so `NotBefore` may well be used in any of the other profiles in there.